# How to change one character for another on a keyboard layout in KDE/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, x11, kde-plasma, keyboard-layout

I would like to enter @ sign when I type № on my Russian keyboard layout.

I'm using KDE 4.13 on Ubuntu system.

I understand that I need to modify the layout somehow. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably start by using `xev` to figure out the keycode sent by your keyboard for №, then use `xmodmap` to remap that key.